# How to check in(versioning) jpg or pdf files programmatically in sharepoint site?

Tags: development

Right now, i know how to check in word documents in sharepoint site. Now, i need to check in for jpg or pdf files. Does anyone know how and if it's even better, provide for me codes to implement this. Thank you.

```
  [WebMethod(EnableSession = true, Description = "Typical Web Method")]
    public string CheckoutFile(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            //url = "http://it3127:30091/Shared%20Documents/Folder1/Testing%20new%20document.docx";
            SPSite site = new SPSite(url);
            SPWeb oWebsite = site.OpenWeb();
            //SPFolder oFolder = oWebsite.Folders["Shared Documents"];
            //SPFileCollection collFiles = oFolder.Files;

            SPFile file = oWebsite.GetFile(url);
            file.CheckOut();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "false";
        }
        return "true";
    }
```

Comment: It should be no real difference, can you show us your code sp we can see where it goes wrong? :)

Comment: @RobertLindgren hi robert. i do not have the codes for check in as it is already a built-in for Outlook 2010. Also, i have set the settings in SharePoint to require check-in. So i just nid to checkout it. My Checkout codes is on top.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void publishItemStyle(string url)
 {
     SPSite site = new SPSite(url);
     SPWeb oWebsite = site.OpenWeb();

     try
     {
         SPFile file = web.GetFile("Style Library/Xsl Style Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl");

         if (file.Level == SPFileLevel.Checkout)
             file.CheckIn("", SPCheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
         if (file.Level == SPFileLevel.Draft)
         {
             if (file.DocumentLibrary.EnableModeration) file.Approve("");
             else file.Publish("");
         }
        file.Update();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         // Some logging
     }
     finally{
         oWebsite.Dispose();
         site.Dispose();
     }
}
```

Modified example from here http://jeff-sharepoint-note.blogspot.se/2011/07/publish-and-approve-file.html

Can easily be improved with using statements for SPSite and SPSite instead

Comment: Also, if you use this method exactly, watch for concurrency bugs - you could be modifying the file outside this method, using another instance of SPSite, then call this method and attempt to save 'changes' to a file handle that isn't associated to the SPSite instance created here.